# conditions for If Else (with number of decimal places)

Tags: java, decimal, if-statement

Is there a way to execute a piece of code depending on how many decimal places there are in a number. For instance, if the double was just 2.0 i would want to convert it to an integer, but if it were 2.43426 i would want to leave it as a double. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of how this would be useful?  (bearing in mind that Java is a statically-typed language)

Comment: i would be converting them to strings and writing them out, so i would want it to say 3 instead of 3.0, but not 3 instead of 3.4324. I may be doing this the completely wrong way haha

Comment: Then this is just a question of formatting for output purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but would:

```
double d = 2.0;

if ((long) d == d) {
    // then
}
```

Work for you? That only answers your question in that particular case.

Comment: I will try it; that seems like it would work. I'll accept your answer if it does!

Comment: You should consider using `long` rather than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify precision and convert like this:

```
double precision = 1e-10;

int rounded = Math.round(x);
if (Math.abs(x-rounded) > precision) System.out.print(x)
else System.out.print(rounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the double to String
2. Using regex, find the decimal point and then get the number of characters after that.
3. Use it in your if-else

Answer (score 0):

A *quick and dirty* solution would be the following:

```
double foo = 2.43426;
int count = String.valueOf(foo).split(".")[1].toCharArray().length;
if(count > 1){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're after:

> i would be converting them to strings and writing them out, so i would want it to say 3 instead of 3.0, but not 3 instead of 3.4324.

Then the "correct" way is using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
assert "3".equals(fmt.format(3.0));
assert "3.4324".equals(fmt.format(3.4324));
```

It does, however, localize the decimal separator (I get a comma rather than a dot). If that's an issue, you can just call `fmt.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ROOT))`.